# Problems trying to port an Objective C completion block into Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks

I'm using a third party library written in objective C with the following method:

```
- (void)manageServerResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response NSData:(NSData*)data andNSError:(NSError*)error onComplete:(void (^)(NSInteger kindOfError, NSDictionary*jsonResponse))onComplete;
```

when I port it to swift I do the following:

```
typealias ResponseCompletedBlock = (NSInteger, NSDictionary?) -> Void
...
let completedResponseMethod : ResponseCompletedBlock = {(kindOfError: NSInteger, jsonResponse: NSDictionary?) -> Void in
    self.onComplete(kindOfError, jsonResponse: jsonResponse)}

let responseManager: ResponseManager = ResponseManager.sharedResponseManager() as! ResponseManager
responseManager.manageServerResponse(response, 
    NSData: data, 
    andNSError: error, 
    onComplete: completedResponseMethod)
```

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot invoke 'manageServerResponse' with an argument list of type
>   '(NSURLResponse?, NSData: NSData?, andNSError: NSError?, onComplete:
>   ResponseCompletedBlock)'

and if I replace the last sentence for

```
responseManager.manageServerResponse(response, 
    NSData: data, 
    andNSError: error, 
    onComplete: nil)
```

everything works, so I assume that the problem is with the block structure, but I've tried to change everything and the error remains.

Can you help?

Comment: I'm not that experienced with Swift yet, but did you try making `NSDictionary` implicitly unwrapped in your `(NSInteger, NSDictionary?) -> Void` closure?

Comment: In swift blocks you often need to figure out what needs to be unwrapped or not - explicitly. Adding a ! or ? might solve the issue. Generally ! solves it for me...

Comment: I've tried several things, including adding ! and ? to the NSDictionary parameter. No luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSDictionary *` is mapped to Swift as `[NSObject : AnyObject]!`,
therefore the type of the response block should be

```
typealias ResponseCompletedBlock = (Int, [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void
```

and consequently

```
let completedResponseMethod = {(kindOfError: Int, jsonResponse: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void in
    // ...
}
```

One method to figure out the correct Swift signature of functions  is to use the *autocompletion* in Xcode:
You start typing

```
 responseManager.manageServerResponse(
```

and Xcode suggests

[image]

Comment: @F.D.FDev: You are welcome! – I have added some information about how you can solve this kind of problems generally.

Comment: Thanks for that, although my Xcode refuses to autocomplete code from ObjC in a Swift file... don't know why (And I've deleted derived data if you ask so)

Answer (score 1):

Per [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html):

> When you bridge from an `NSDictionary` object to a Swift dictionary, the resulting dictionary is of type `[NSObject: AnyObject]`.

Also, unless the Objective-C code is annotated for nullability, the Swift dictionary is an implicitly-unwrapped optional. Therefore your typealias should look like this:

```
typealias ResponseCompletedBlock = (NSInteger, [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void
```

I'd also recommend changing the `NSInteger` to `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `typealias` and `completedResponseMethod` absolutely necessary for your program to function? If not, this would probably solve your problem:

```
responseManager.manageServerResponse(response, NSData: data, andNSError: error, onComplete: { 
    $0, $1 in
    self.onComplete($0, jsonResponse: $1)
}
```

As your error suggests, the error was due to a type mismatch. If you use the default local parameters, you'll be able to work around that particular problem.

Comment: Not at all, I added the type alias just to try to split all the problem into parts. In fact it was just one line of code at the beginning...